# Django / Models / Admin / Problem with the foreign key : __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys, admin

I have already tried multiple solutions find on other topics but nothing works.

I have a problem the foreign key in Django Admin. Impossible to see a records or add a new record.

I have a table `convertion_factor` with no NULL values. [see postgreSQL config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mWy5.png)

This is my model :

```
class convertion_factor(models.Model):
    foodID = models.ForeignKey('food_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    measureID = models.ForeignKey('measure_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    conversionFactorValue = models.FloatField()
    convFactorDateOfEntry = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False)
```

In order to views the data in Django Admin, you have to add `def __str__(self):`  to the model. Ok let's do that :

```
class convertion_factor(models.Model):
    foodID = models.ForeignKey('food_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    measureID = models.ForeignKey('measure_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    conversionFactorValue = models.FloatField()
    convFactorDateOfEntry = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False) 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.conversionFactorValue
```

Now when I go to Django Admin and I click on the model `convertion_factor` I can see the table just fine but when I try to click on a record to edit it, I have this error :

[TypeError at /admin/kalo/convertion_factor/19505/change/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LoTZL.png)

```
Exception Type: TypeError at /admin/kalo/convertion_factor/19505/change/
Exception Value: __str__ returned non-string (type float)
```

I have the impression this is an error due to the foreign key because with my others models without a foreign key, everythings work just fine.

In the function `def __str__(self):` I have tried :

`return self.foodID.__str__` but same error

`return str(self.foodID)` but same error

Do you have any idea ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does `return str(self.foodID)` give the same error?

Comment: Yes, exactly the same. @bichanna

Answer (score 0):

This code works correctly with float values, and it will return a float value in the form of a string value.

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.conversionFactorValue)
```

I have added a screenshot below.

[image: django admin page view]

Comment: Yes I tried it. I can display the data just like your screenshot but if I click on the data 14.6 I still have the error :

`TypeError at /admin/kalo/food_name/503380/change/`

`__str__ returned non-string (type tuple)`

@BharatNaik